# configure wamp server

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I installed wamp server2 in windows7 64 bit. after installing when I start wampserver it goes offline. and all the components like localhost, apache does not work.when I try to put it online it shows 'Could not execute menu item(internal error)[exception].Could not perform service action' message as error . when I run wamp as admin it goes online but still the localhost does not work. what can I do to make it work.

Comment: I have installed visual studio also for the asp.net so it might be using default port. Can I run wamp server in different port??

Comment: I have decided to change default port to 8080 ie

Comment: click the WAMP server icon > Apache > httpd.conf, then change the line Listen 80 to Listen 8080 or any port you want.

Answer (score 2):

It could be a conflict with Skype...

If you have Skype, go in skype advance options and check use alternative port. (Can't remember exactly what is the option but it will make skype use another port and solve the conflict)

Comment: I have already uninstalled skype

Comment: When you run it as admin, you see wamp icon with the green light like if everything was fine ? Did you try to access localhost using 127.0.0.1?

Comment: it goes online but no green light. and I cannot turn it to offline without exiting wamp server.